# What does a trivia themed party mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Recently I came across the following sentence,

> My birthday party was a trivia themed party.

I tried to find what it means by a trivia themed party, but couldn’t get what it is. Can someone help?

Comment: If you were invited to a _Trivia Themed Party_, I'm sure your hosts would not mind if you were to ask them "so, what does that mean exactly" - it's pretty vague.  The root of "trivia" in this usage is the game _Trivial Pursuit_, that came out in the 1980s and ended up wildly popular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Pursuit.

Comment: I've been in a Trivial Pursuit-themed quiz team. I was in green from head to toe including mortarboard hat and printed circuit board T-shirt,  we had someone in a yellow toga, another in a pink wig and pink inflatable guitar, etc.  You'd want to ask what precisely they meant before going to those lengths.  But (@Flydog57) I'm not sure Trivial Pursuit is the root, though it's the best-known trivia game - and one in which the playing pieces seem to chase each other round the board rather like the pursuit cycling event in a velodrome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

'Trivia' is an extremely broad term. It could mean information (usually general knowledge, minor details) about almost *any subject*. A themed-party is normally centred around a *specific subject*.

However, 'trivia' has become synonymous with *quizzes* - games or competitions in which you answer questions about general knowledge. My best guess would be that a 'trivia-themed party' is a party where *quizzes* play a part.

Comment: It would also be my guess that it means there might be quizzes, but I'd probably ask for clarification, since it's kind of an unusual way to phrase that. "X-themed" (e.g. 80's-themed) usually includes how people should generally dress, what music and decorations there may be and, yes, also which activities there may be. It's a bit more general than just "we will do this thing". For that I might simply say "We had trivia at my party", "My party was a trivia night" or something like that.